# Is there a way to automate extraction of elements from two or more lists?

Tags: r, list, extract, google-trends

My goal is to automate fetching of trends data along with the extraction of `"interest_over_time"` from the lists.

Considering it a two-step problem:

- Automating fetching of data based on a group of keywords
- Extracting elements automatically in a methodical manner

I am not able to complete step 2.

Any ideas on how to get this done?

Step1 - Automating fetch of google trends data

```
library(gtrendsR)
a <- c("sony", "apple")

for (i in a) {
  name <- (paste(i, sep=""))
  assign(name, gtrends(keyword=i, time="now 1-H"))
  print(name)
}
```

Step2 - Extracting elements

```
sony[["interest_over_time"]]
```

instead of doing it like above manually, can I use for or some other function to automate this?

Comment: It is not clear where "interest_over_time" comes from. It's not in your code

Comment: The function `gtrendsR::gtrends()` returns a list of 7. `interest_over_time` is one of the 7 returned `data.frame` objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways that I think will give you what you want.

```
library(gtrendsR)

a = c("sony","apple")
```

**First Way:** using `base` R

```
gtrends_interest <- function(keyword) gtrends(keyword = keyword, time = "now 1-H")[["interest_over_time"]]
trends_data <- do.call('rbind', lapply(a, gtrends_interest))
```

**Second Way:** using `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
trends_data2 <- a %>%
  map_df( ~ gtrends(keyword = ., time = "now 1-H")[["interest_over_time"]])
```

Both methods will return a `data.frame` with the `interest_over_time` from each element in `a` stacked.

I prefer the second since `map()` becomes very powerful once you get a hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

You could read in with `sapply`. The data will be stored into list `l`.

```
library(gtrendsR)
l <- sapply(c("sony", "apple"), function(i) gtrends(keyword=i, time="now 1-H"))
```

Access the data with `l[[1]]` and `l[[2]]`.

```
head(l[[1]])
#                  date hits keyword   geo gprop category
# 1 2019-04-21 09:14:00   74    sony world   web        0
# 2 2019-04-21 09:15:00   72    sony world   web        0
# 3 2019-04-21 09:16:00   75    sony world   web        0
# 4 2019-04-21 09:17:00   84    sony world   web        0
# 5 2019-04-21 09:18:00   78    sony world   web        0
# 6 2019-04-21 09:19:00   83    sony world   web        0

head(l[[2]])
# location hits keyword   geo gprop
# 1 Falkland Islands (Islas Malvinas)   NA    sony world   web
# 2            SÃ£o TomÃ© & PrÃ­ncipe   NA    sony world   web
# 3                        Seychelles   NA    sony world   web
# 4                 St. Kitts & Nevis   NA    sony world   web
# 5                         Hong Kong  100    sony world   web
# 6                             Nepal   84    sony world   web
```